# JSON doesn't get any value from parameter in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I was using this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-comments-section in my project and while setting the current user to the parameter user (i.e when i do `currentUserFullName: user.currentUserFullName`), the value doesn't seem to set when I post the comment.

Note that `<h1>{user.currentUserFullName}</h1>` this shows output correctly and `comments` is also working fine when I assign `commentData={comments}`

```js
import { CommentSection } from 'react-comments-section';
import 'react-comments-section/dist/index.css';

function Comments({comments,user}){

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{user.currentUserFullName}</h1>
      
      <CommentSection
        currentUser={{
          currentUserId: '213',
          currentUserImg:
            'https://ui-avatars.com/api/name=Riya&background=random',
          currentUserProfile:
            'https://www.linkedin.com/in/',
          currentUserFullName: user.currentUserFullName
        }}
        logIn={{
          loginLink: 'http://localhost:3001/',
          signupLink: 'http://localhost:3001/'
        }}

        overlayStyle={{ 
            width: '70%',
            margin: 'auto'
        }}

        comment-titleStyle={{
            fontFamily: "Gill Sans"
        }}
        
        commentData={comments}
        
        onSubmitAction={(data: {|
          userId: string,
          comId: string,
          avatarUrl: string,
          userProfile?: string,
          fullName: string,
          text: string,
          replies: any,
          commentId: string
          |}) => {
            console.log('parent comment, ', data)
          }
        }

        onReplyAction={(data: {|
          userId: string,
          comId: string,
          avatarUrl: string,
          userProfile?: string,
          fullName: string,
          text: string,
          replies: any,
          commentId: string
          |}) => {
            console.log('reply comment, ', data)
          }
        }

        currentData={(data: any) => {
          console.log('curent data', data)
          // console.log('comments here', comments)
          console.log('user here', user)
        }}
      />
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default Comments;
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is inside comments props?

Comment: Is there any error the console gives you?

Comment: no, there is no error. when i post a comment `currentUserFullName` is set to `undefined`

Comment: this is `comments` from documentation : https://riyanegi.github.io/react-comments-documentation/#Props

Comment: `currentUser={user}` also doesn't work